# Transferring and Deleting Data in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use Google Apps Script to create a function that will search for word `Yes` in a specific column in my Google Spreadsheet.

If it finds `Yes`, it will then continue to copy those entire rows onto a different spreadsheet saved to my google drive and then delete it from the original spreadsheet.

I have little to none experience with this language, but I have made some code.

I am looking for a correct way to execute this and how to complete my code. What would you do?

Newest code edit:

```
function moveDelete() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var dsh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  var data = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow()-1).getValues();
  var range = sh.getRange(1, 1, data.length);


  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {3
    var array = data[i]
    if (array[4] == 'Yes') {
      dsh.appendRow(array);
      sh.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};

function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Send to Record",
    functionName : "moveDelete"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Custom Menu", entries);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1 - transfer to the same document:**

```
function moveDelete() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var dsh= ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');  
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
    var array = data[i]
    if (data[i][4] == 'Yes') {
      dsh.appendRow(array);
      sh.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};
```

**Solution 2 (based on comment) - transfer to another spreadsheet file:**

```
function moveDelete() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ts = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id of the target spreadsheet here"); // example: 31d6k7iXh20rjLn22m0axvscR6-BcyOy_fxhdk-ResXU
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // Sheet1 of the source spreadsheet
  var dsh= ts.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); // Sheet2 of the target spreadsheet
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
    var array = data[i]
    if (data[i][4] == 'Yes') {
      dsh.appendRow(array);
      sh.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};
```

**Note** that 1. uses `4` as an index which checks for the **5th** column which is **column E**. Make sure to get the index number right to pick the desired column.

Comment: I have made the changes, however, now it give me this error code: "The parameters () don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange"

Comment: Does `Sheet1` exist ? @CristianGarcia

Comment: Yes, it does exist

Comment: Apparently I need to include parameters with the 'getRange()' method

Comment: Then use your original code . Select Sheet1 and run the script. @CristianGarcia

Comment: Now it is telling me that 'getNumRows()' is not a valid method. Any idea how I can figure out the number of rows?

Comment: Check my updated answer. use data.length in the for loop instead and remove `numRows` from the script altogether@CristianGarcia

Comment: Now it gives me error: 'sh.getValues is not a function (line 5, file "Code")'. I am going to keep debugging it, but this helps

Comment: It does not make sense. Please check again if the name of the sheets are correct. For example check if you mistaken put spaces in `Sheet1` for example `Sheet1 ` or ` Sheet1` . @CristianGarcia

Comment: I debugged it, however, nothing changes when the function executes. The sheets stay the same.

Comment: The code works fantastically, but I was thinking towards implementing it to copy the rows to a completely different google spreadsheet in my google drive. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: 1) edit your question to ask regarding that. 2) do you have edit access to both files? @CristianGarcia

Comment: I do have access to both files

Comment: @CristianGarcia I updated my answer. Please click on the **tick** button to the left of the answer to mark it as accepted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I know this took a lot of your time, so thank you very much

Comment: I am happy that your issue was resolved :) @CristianGarcia